# How did Korg start the revolution which succeeded in overthrowing the Grandmaster in the end?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok* movie, when Thor first met Korg:

> Thor: How did you end up here?
>
> Korg: Well, I tried to start a revolution, but didn't print enough pamphlets so hardly anyone turned up. Except for my mum and her boyfriend, who I hate. As punishment, I was forced to be in here and become a gladiator. Bit of a promotional disaster that one, but I'm actually organizing another revolution. I don't know if you'd be interested in something like that? Do you reckon you'd be interested?

Later, when Korg gained his freedom,

> he talked about starting the revolution, but then hit into Loki who lead him to Asgard through Devil's Anus.

In the after-credit scene of the movie, we saw that

> Grandmaster was overthrown by the revolution. He even declared that the uprising was good and it couldn’t have been done without him because you need someone to rise against, and that they should call the whole thing a tie. :)

When did Korg get the time to print and distribute pamphlets to start the revolution which succeeded in overthrowing the Grandmaster?

Comment: Why did he have to print pamphlets this time? Was the gladiators being released by the Valkyrie not enough to get the gladiators taking back their rights?

Comment: His initial conversation with Thor would seem to imply that he's already started distributing pamphlets.

Comment: @Edlothiad He obviously tried to start the revolution outside the prison before he got captured. Those guys in after-credit scene looked like scrappers, not gladiators.

Comment: I don't see where that was ever obvious, unless you mean the first revolution, then you still haven't answered my question.

Comment: @Edlothiad Yes, I meant the first revolution. What I want to say is Korg wasn't trying to push Gladiators (who were imprisoned), but the outsiders (citizens of Sakaar) who might be interested. Talking about Gladiators, they would most likely fly out of the system. Also, there weren't enough Gladiators to beat the security of Grandmaster. All the gladiators which were shown on-screen actually joined Korg and Loki to go to Asgard.

Comment: How do you know the first revolution was on Sakaar?

Comment: @Edlothiad How is this even a confusion? Are you saying that Korg is just a lunatic who wants to start a revolution for fun?

Comment: Korg first revolution could've been on his home-world, which was somewhere other than Sakaar , that's how I understood it at least, which may be entirely wrong. Anyways, my first question was. "Why did he have to print pamphlets for this revolution?" Couldn't he just have spread the news by word of mouth?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something we last see Korg on a ship with Thor and the Asgardians, he's not in the post credits scene with the Grandmaster so it seems unlikely he's actually involved in the revolution? He went with Loki straight after being freed on Sakaar to Asgard, so surely could not have had anything to do with the revolution that brings down the Grandmaster, perhaps it's lead by some of other former gladiators freed by Thor.

Comment: By taking it literally, you're missing the point of the 'pamphlets' joke.

Comment: @InfinityWar - Loosely related; In Thor: The Dark World near the beginning the big rock giant that Thor kills on Vanaheim appears to be a Kronan as well... perhaps that is where he started his first revolution?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

- The pamphlets refer to how Korg became a gladiator initially.
- Korg didn't take the time to make any pamphlets the second time.
- Valkyrie broke into the room to free Korg and the others for the successful revolution.
- The Grandmaster first learned about the revolution when his second in command informed him the "prisoners with jobs" had all escaped and armed themselves.

So I am not 100% on what you are asking, which is why I never answered this the first time I saw it, but after getting a chance to rewatch the movie I will take a stab at answering it...

So the pamphlets Korg was talking about referred to the first revolution that he tried to start. (I also think 'pamphlets' was meant to be a joke about not convincing enough people to revolt with him) We do not know where that was or why he tried to start a revolution, but as punishment he was forced to become a gladiator. As Thor points out Korg is Kronan.

Given the numerous realms we know exist (Hela says instead of stopping at nine Asgard should have conquered them all) is is possible the Kronans are in a different one and that Korg tried to start a revolution there. Of course, when it failed he was sent to Sakaar to become a gladiator as punishment.

Later in the film Valkyrie breaks into the room where the gladiators are, gives Korg a gun, and says "The Lord of Thunder sends his best." To this Korg says "The revolution has begun" and charges the weapon he was given. This is how he escapes and starts his new successful revolution that sees the downfall of the Grandmaster.

Korg and company also don't hang around after revolution (only trying to escape) and they join with Loki, fly to Asgard, save the day, and then fly off into the sunset with Thor at the fore.